# Berkeley DB: stuck at futex_wait because of previous abnormal quit during c api call

Tags: linux, berkeley-db, futex, c-api

I'm programming in C, using berkeley db 4.3 (/usr/lib64/libdb-4.3.so) on RHEL5.6 with kernel 2.6.18-238_xen_AMD64.

In my tests (writing 1,000,000 key/value pairs), if one process quitted abnormally (ctrl + c, kill, or assert fails) while an operation on the db is in process, later operation on that db would be blocked upon opening. Strace shows that the process stuck at a futex(ptr_to_something, FUTEX_WAIT, 2, NULL) call after opening the __db.00x(e.g __db.001, __db.002, __db.003) files.

The only way I know to clear the lock is to remove __db.00x files, and following tests showed that the database is not damaged. It meets my requirement, but I'm just wondering whether there's a better(or more elegant) way to solve this problem.

Here I listed some strace stderr and the code to operate the database which may help.

*some of the strace stderr*

```
...  
open("__db.001", O_RDWR)                = 3  
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0  
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=24576, ...}) = 0  
close(3)                                = 0  
open("__db.001", O_RDWR)                = 3  
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0  
mmap(NULL, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x2afcc4149000  
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0x2afcc4149000, FUTEX_WAIT, 2, NULL **[[stuck here]]**
```

*code to operate the database*

```
typedef DB* db_handle;
db_handle bdb_open(const char *filename, u_int32_t cache_size_mb)
{
    int ret;
    DB_ENV *env;
    db_handle dbp;
    u_int32_t flags = DB_CREATE | DB_THREAD | DB_INIT_LOCK | DB_INIT_MPOOL | DB_INIT_LOCK ;
    u_int32_t gb = cache_size_mb / 1024, mb = cache_size_mb % 1024;

    if (ret = db_env_create(&env, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "db_env_create:%d, %s\n", ret, db_strerror(ret));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (ret = env->set_timeout(env, 3 * 1000000, DB_SET_LOCK_TIMEOUT)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "env->set_timeout:%d, %s\n", ret, db_strerror(ret));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (ret = env->set_lk_detect(env, DB_LOCK_DEFAULT)) { /* this seems to be of no use in my case */
        fprintf(stderr, "env->set_lk_detect:%d, %s\n", ret, db_strerror(ret));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (ret = env->set_cachesize(env, gb, mb * 1024 * 1024, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "env->set_cachesize:%d, %s\n", ret, db_strerror(ret));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((ret = env->open(env, NULL, flags, 0)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "db_env_open:%d, %s\n", ret, db_strerror(ret));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (ret = db_create(&dbp, env, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "db_create:%d, %s\n", ret, db_strerror(ret));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (ret = dbp->open(dbp, NULL, filename, NULL, DB_BTREE, flags, 0664)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dbp->open:%d, %s\n", ret, db_strerror(ret));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return dbp;
}

int bdb_put(db_handle db, void* key, u_int32_t keylen, void* val, u_int32_t vallen)
{
    DBT dkey, dval;
    bzero(&dkey, sizeof(dkey));
    bzero(&dval, sizeof(dval));
    dkey.data = key, dkey.size = keylen;
    dval.data = val, dval.size = vallen;
    return db->put(db, NULL, &dkey, &dval, 0);
}

int bdb_get(db_handle db, void* key, const u_int32_t keylen,
                          void* buf, u_int32_t buflen, u_int32_t* nwrite)
{
    DBT dkey, dval;
    bzero(&dkey, sizeof(dkey));
    bzero(&dval, sizeof(dval));
    dkey.data = key, dkey.size = keylen;
    dval.data = buf, dval.ulen = buflen, dval.flags = DB_DBT_USERMEM;
    int ret = db->get(db, NULL, &dkey, &dval, 0);
    if (ret == 0 && nwrite != NULL)
        *nwrite = dval.size;
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The __db* files contain the names of locks, but not the locks themselves.

The pthread locks are implemented on top of kernel futexes. The process
that was killed likely had an active lock when killed.

Try running "db_recover -h $DBHOME" to clear stale locks.

There is also a callback that can be added to automate "stale lock"
remover.

(aside)
Your code almost certainly needs to handle DB_RUNRECOVERY and DB_VERSION_MISMATCH
error codes from env->open for a robust implementation. Reopen with DB_RECOVER
set will handle.

On older linux, there is also the possibility of "stale futexes" (i.e. a futex
that was locked by a process that died) that can only be cleared by
rebooting (there is another way, using "robust mutexes", that sets
a flag that permits another process to unlock previously locked mutexes,
but that isn't implemented in Berkeley DB).